# Atom Electron: Render Canvas in Another Window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, angular, electron

I have an Electron app with two `BrowserWindows`. The first manages multiple mediastreams which are rendered onto a canvas. When running the app in the browser I can access the canvas in a popup using the document reference provided by `window.open()`. Is something like this possible in Electron?

Is it possible to pass a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` using the  `ipcRenderer` to the other window? Or via a global on the main process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` do not support complex things transfer like objects or functions. You need to send your instructions from your first `BrowserWindow` to your main process, then the main process should send an instruction (like a string) to your second window that should handle it.

If you want to transfer streams, you will have to create a localhost server and use a socket library ([socket.io](http://socket.io)), coupled with the corresponding npm package, for example [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream)

Comment: The problem is that video cannot be be rendered using just a string. I would need to pass either the mediastream or the `video` element.

Comment: While that would work, it is essentially a rewrite for something that already works fine in the normal browser scope.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that there are no other great solution. Even BrowserWindowProxy can only send strings http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.5/api/window-open/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe WebRTC could work for you, example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/